# Short story about pollster who discovers residents grouped by behavior type for easy manipulation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Sophisticated, wheelchair-bound pollster/ad man discovers voters have been grouped in residential neighborhoods by behavior type for easy manipulation.  Triggered by smells, sounds, etc., they converge/attack & he barely escapes, using every tool built into his high-tech conveyance.

It’s 40+ years since I read this.  I have no recollection of title or author, but my memories of the story theme have been especially vivid through the Trump era.

Comment: Your story is *Greenplace* as asked and  answered here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/229171/28516 If you agree, please comment saying so and we can close this as a duplicate without writing another answer.

Comment: Yes! I'd searched, but didn't recall enough detail/keywords to turn up the other question.  Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for confirming the ID in the other question, and welcome to sf stack exchange!