# Looking for a story where a man is killed because he entered a neighborhood where he has the wrong personality type

Tags: story-identification

A man wanders into a neighborhood where are the people have personality types different from his and they beat him to death.

This happens because the rulers of the society manipulate where people live as a way of controlling people.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this story as described doesn't seem to contain any scifi or fantasy elements.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain more about the SF aspects of this work?  What were the personality types?  Was this a short story?  When and where did you read this?

Comment: This does sound it could be some sort of Silverberg story where regions have been split based off of personality types instead of nationalities.

Comment: Sounds like it might be from a dystopian future kind of story, which, AFAIK, is on topic.

Comment: @Basya - Yes, this certainly doesn't sound like our mundane world.

Comment: This actually reminds me of something I saw mentioned on the site recently -- some world where a certain category of people have a specific quality that makes them very disliked (some kind of telepathy or something), and they get killed for it much as described here.

Comment: Is it old (1960s)? Could this be *Greenplace* by Tom Purdom? The protagonist doesn't actually get killed but does get attacked.  More details here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/229183/28516